# Актуальность перечислений

Tags: c#, проектирование

Уважаемые, помогите разобраться. Наткнулся в книге Марка Симана "Внедрение зависимостей в .net" на такое выражение: "Перечисления уже не используются и должны быть переработаны в полиморфические классы". Так вот хочется узнать действительно ли это так, и все отказываются от перечислений ? Или это дело субъективное ?

Comment: эта фраза явно вырвана из контекста и судя по всему имеет абсолютно иной смысл.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Никто от перечислений не отказывается. Они активном используются как в самом фреймворке, так и во всех популярных библиотеках.

Полиморфные классы вместо перечислений - это, конечно, хорошо. Но городить иерархию вместо энума вообще *во всех случаях* - это овердизайн.

Да, классический code smell вида switch + enum в коде скорее всего стоит заменить иерархией.

Но, например, заводить иерархию из 4-х классов ради свойства вида ConnectionState.Open/Closed/Faulted лично я бы не стал.

Другой стандартный пример использования энумов - задание опций. Посмотрите стандартный класс Regex/[RegexOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) и представьте сколько кода пришлось бы написать ради нескольких битовых флагов.

Или, например - у иерархий есть особенности при сохранении значений в базу, что, при активном использовании их вместо энумов приведёт к страшно перегруженной и нестабильной схеме.

Вобщем, автор книги явно перегибает палку. Пользуйтесь энумами сколько вам угодно.